# How to calculate price change over 3 years in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to calculate the price change of an item (both in cost and % change) over the last three years.

The table has four fields:

`SKU_no, Date_updated, Price, Active_flag`

When the `Active_flag` field is `A`, the item is active, when `I` it is inactive. Some items haven't changed prices in years so they won't have three years of entries with an inactive flag.

Sample table

```
      SKU_NO       Update_date        Price        Active_flag
      30           1/1/1999           40.8            I
      33           1/1/2014           70.59           A
      33           1/1/2013           67.23           I
      33           1/1/2012           60.03           I
      33           1/1/2011           55.08           I
      33           1/1/2010           55.08           I
      34           1/1/2009           51              A
      36           1/1/2014           70.59           A
      36           1/1/2013           67.23           I
      36           1/1/2012           60.03           I
      38           1/1/2002           43.32           A
      38           1/1/2001           43.32           I
      38           4/8/2000           43.32           I
      38           1/1/1999           43.32           I
      39           1/1/2014           73.08           A
      39           1/1/2013           69.6            I
      39           1/1/2012           62.13           I
      39           1/1/2011           57              I
      39           1/1/2010           57              I
      39           1/1/2009           52.8            I
```

This is the first query I wrote. I'm not too familiar with complex calculations

```
select 
    s.VENDOR,
    s.FISCAL_YEAR,
    s.FISCAL_MONTH_NO,
    s.FISCAL_YEAR||'_'||FISCAL_MONTH_NO as PERIOD, 
CASE WHEN S.COST_USED_FLAG IN ('CONTRACT') THEN 'CONTRACT' ELSE 'NON-CONTRACT' END AS CONTRACT_TYPE,
CASE WHEN ((s.FISCAL_YEAR = 2014 AND FISCAL_MONTH_NO <=9) OR (FISCAL_YEAR = 2013 AND FISCAL_MONTH_NO >=10)) THEN 'CP_1'
     WHEN ((s.FISCAL_YEAR = 2013 AND FISCAL_MONTH_NO <= 9) OR (FISCAL_YEAR = 2012 AND FISCAL_MONTH_NO >=10)) THEN 'CP_2'
     WHEN ((s.FISCAL_YEAR = 2012 AND FISCAL_MONTH_NO <= 9) OR (FISCAL_YEAR = 2011 AND FISCAL_MONTH_NO >=10)) THEN 'CP_3'
     ELSE 'NULL' END CAGR_PERIODS,
    CASE WHEN s.MARKET IN ('PO', 'SC', 'OC') THEN 'PC' ELSE 'EC' END AS MARKET_TYPE,   
    s.MARKET, 
    s.COST_PLUS_FLAG,
    s.COST_USED_FLAG,
    LPAD(S.PC_ITEM_NO,6,'0') AS NEW_ITEM_NO,
    s.PC_ITEM_NO,
    i.ITEM_NO,
    i.VEND_CAT_NUM,
    i.DESCRIPTION,
    s.PC_PROD_CAT,
    s.PC_PROD_SUBCAT,
    i.SELL_UOM,
    i.QTY_PER_SELL_UOM,
    i.PRIMARY_UOM,
    i.HEAD_CONV_FACT,
    SUM(s.QTY_EACH) AS QUANTITY_SOLD, 
    SUM(s.EXT_GROSS_COGS) AS TOTAL_COGS, 
    SUM(s.EXT_GROSS_COGS)/ SUM(s.QTY_EACH) as NET_SALES, 
    SUM(s.EXT_SALES)/ SUM(s.QTY_EACH) as ASP,
    SUM(s.EXT_SALES) AS TOTAL_SALES,
    SUM(S.EXT_SALES) - SUM(S.EXT_GROSS_COGS) as GROSS_PROFIT
    from SIXSIGMA.CIA_ALL_SALES_TREND_DATA  s
    INNER JOIN MGMSH.ITEM i
    ON S.PC_ITEM_NO = I.ITEM_NO
    WHERE S.VENDOR = 'BD' AND
    (S.EXT_SALES IS NOT NULL AND S.FISCAL_YEAR IN ('2013','2012','2011'))
    GROUP BY 
    s.VENDOR,
    s.FISCAL_YEAR,
    s.FISCAL_MONTH_NO, 
    s.FISCAL_YEAR||'_'||FISCAL_MONTH_NO,
    CASE WHEN s.MARKET IN ('PO', 'SC', 'OC') THEN 'PC' ELSE 'EC' END,
    CASE WHEN S.COST_USED_FLAG IN ('CONTRACT') THEN 'CONTRACT' ELSE 'NON-CONTRACT' END,
    CASE WHEN ((s.FISCAL_YEAR = 2014 AND FISCAL_MONTH_NO <=9) OR (FISCAL_YEAR = 2013 AND  FISCAL_MONTH_NO >=10)) THEN 'CP_1'
    WHEN ((s.FISCAL_YEAR = 2013 AND FISCAL_MONTH_NO <= 9) OR (FISCAL_YEAR = 2012 AND FISCAL_MONTH_NO >=10)) THEN 'CP_2'
    WHEN ((s.FISCAL_YEAR = 2012 AND FISCAL_MONTH_NO <= 9) OR (FISCAL_YEAR = 2011 AND FISCAL_MONTH_NO >=10)) THEN 'CP_3'
     ELSE 'NULL' END,
    s.MARKET, 
    s.COST_USED_FLAG,
    s.COST_PLUS_FLAG,
    s.PC_ITEM_NO,
    s.PC_PROD_CAT,
    i.SELL_UOM,
    i.QTY_PER_SELL_UOM,
    i.PRIMARY_UOM,
    i.HEAD_CONV_FACT,
    i.DESCRIPTION,
    i.VEND_CAT_NUM,
    s.PC_PROD_SUBCAT,
    i.ITEM_NO
    ORDER BY s.PC_ITEM_NO,s.FISCAL_YEAR, s.FISCAL_MONTH_NO
```

Comment: You need to show at least you have first tried yourself?

Comment: This is but a small part of what I'm trying to do:

Comment: I have 5 tables, this is what I've written so far:

Comment: its too long, don't worry about it

Comment: Have you written some sql query yet?

Comment: @Mark Wilson - when you say it's too long; is that too long to post the code in the question by editing or in the comment? Any code should  be posted within the question if possible.

Comment: The query I just posted is to pull the main data, that I can do easily, its complex calculations I need a push in the right direction. The cost table is small with 4 columns but to calculate cost and % differences is what I've never done

Comment: The phrase "calculate the price change of an item (both in cost and % change) over the last three years" is fuzzy. For example, what exactly might the price change of an item in cost over the last three years mean?

Comment: I don't know whether to try something with LEAD or LAG? Maybe something else, just trying to get ideas

Comment: Price change means sku 33 (A), increased 3.36 in cost and 4.76% increase from previous cost. I would be happy to be able to get cost and % increase from previous price to current. I just don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach this, but I would recommend a windowing function such as `LAG` or `LEAD`. With these functions, you can reference neighboring rows. For example:

```
lead(column, offset, default) over (partition by some_column order by column)
```

And in the example below:

```
lead(price, 1, price) over (partition by sku_no order by update_date desc)
```

Here is a working example with sample data:

```
with sample_data as (
      select '30' sku_no, to_date('1/1/1999','DD/MM/YYYY') update_date, 40.8 price, 'I' active_flag from dual union all
      select '33', to_date('1/1/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'), 70.59, 'A' from dual union all
      select '33', to_date('1/1/2013','DD/MM/YYYY'), 67.23, 'I' from dual union all
      select '33', to_date('1/1/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'), 60.03, 'I' from dual union all
      select '33', to_date('1/1/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'), 55.08, 'I' from dual union all
      select '33', to_date('1/1/2010','DD/MM/YYYY'), 55.08, 'I' from dual union all
      select '34', to_date('1/1/2009','DD/MM/YYYY'), 51   , 'A' from dual union all
      select '36', to_date('1/1/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'), 70.59, 'A' from dual union all
      select '36', to_date('1/1/2013','DD/MM/YYYY'), 67.23, 'I' from dual union all
      select '36', to_date('1/1/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'), 60.03, 'I' from dual union all
      select '38', to_date('1/1/2002','DD/MM/YYYY'), 43.32, 'A' from dual union all
      select '38', to_date('1/1/2001','DD/MM/YYYY'), 43.32, 'I' from dual union all
      select '38', to_date('4/8/2000','DD/MM/YYYY'), 43.32, 'I' from dual union all
      select '38', to_date('1/1/1999','DD/MM/YYYY'), 43.32, 'I' from dual union all
      select '39', to_date('1/1/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'), 73.08, 'A' from dual union all
      select '39', to_date('1/1/2013','DD/MM/YYYY'), 69.6 , 'I' from dual union all
      select '39', to_date('1/1/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'), 62.13, 'I' from dual union all
      select '39', to_date('1/1/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'), 57   , 'I' from dual union all
      select '39', to_date('1/1/2010','DD/MM/YYYY'), 57   , 'I' from dual union all
      select '39', to_date('1/1/2009','DD/MM/YYYY'), 52.8 , 'I' from dual)
select
  sku_no,
  update_date,
  price,
  lead(price,1, price) over (partition by sku_no order by update_date desc) prior_price, -- Showing the offset
  price - lead(price,1, price) over (partition by sku_no order by update_date desc) price_difference, -- Calculate the difference 
  round((price - lead(price,1, price) over (partition by sku_no order by update_date desc)) * 100 /price, 2) percent_change -- Calculate the percentage
from sample_data
where update_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'),-36); -- You said in the last three years
```

You can also use `LAG` with a different order by sort. If you want to calculate the difference from three years prior, I would suggest using the `KEEP` function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried the LEAD and LAG before and it was challenging for me. Thought there might be an easlier way. Again, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: You are welcome. Oracle analytic functions and windowing functions are worth learning, they are very useful. If you feel this answer was useful you are encouraged to up vote it or accept as an answer. If not, then no response is necessary.